# python determine if a volume is a cdrom

Tags: python, macos, operating-system

I want to determine in python if a volume is a audio cdrom in order to access the files in it; independent of a player (VLC, pygame etc.)

Pygame dosn't support cdrom any more.

In terminal I can find manually the cdrom as volume and access is no problem, because I know the name of the CD.

But, if I want to determine which volume is a cdrom without knowing the name of the volume I need to check the type of the volumes. I need to do so because the mounting point can change.

My idea ist to loop through the volumes or dev folder and check if a volume is a cdrom-drive.

Comment: can you please rephrase your question: do you want to have a method which takes a drive letter as parameter and return the type or just to list the drives with all their info?

Comment: At the end I want to get the files (tracks) of a audio cd with python.

Comment: this is a completely different thing - you need to assert the following: that the drive is a CD drive; that the CD type is audio/mp3/whatevertype; that the list is readable

Can you please edit your original post and rephrase the question?

Comment: Seems like this could be done by reading the list of mounts and looking for one with the filesystem type cd9660. https://superuser.com/questions/114515/how-can-i-find-what-dev-my-dvd-drive-is